# Codeigniter Extending CI_controller works on localhost but not server

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I created a MY_Base controller class that extends CI_Controller
when I call a controller that extends MY_Base everything works fine on my localhost (using MAMP) however on my server I get

> Fatal error: Class 'MY_Base' not found in
>   /../application/controllers/organization.php on line 3

I am guessing it is in the way server is routing calls but not sure where to even start looking.

Any ideas where I should start looking? 
Thank you.

Comment: Where is MY_Base located? Libraries or Core?

Comment: it is located in application/core

Comment: Try to rename MY_Base to Base_Controller. It might be conflicting.

Comment: Are you using [Modular Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home)? If so, which version of CI and MX? If not: what OS is the server, UNIX? Could be a file name uppercase/lowercase issue. What is the exact name and location of MY_Base? The more info you can provide, the better.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I keep forgetting about the uppercase/lowercase issue! Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When things work on OS X and stop working on Linux, I'd first check for capitalization issues. Did you name the file something like `My_Base.php` -- other UN*X filesystems are case sensitive.